# How to: Browser send JSON to server?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, forms

I have a `<form>`. I want to strip that form (or other HTML) of particular data elements, form them into JSON, and then send that JSON as a request to the domain server, where the server will consume it.

What does the JavaScript look like to do the job described above?

**Note:** I do not need CORS (e.g. no cross-site, it's all same-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Get data in Forms**

You could use the `serializeArray` for the forms. You just need to parse it in the correct way. An example method is provided below

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

Example in action: http://jsfiddle.net/sxGtM/3/

**Get content in HTML elements**

You can get the content of an div or something else by using the `document.getElementById` method and then the `innerHTML` property

```
var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('DIV1');
var content = MyDiv1.innerHTML;
```

**Post object to server using jQuery**

```
function sendData() {
$.ajax({
    url: '/example',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: <Your JSON Object>,
    dataType: 'json'
});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a great answer and quickly!

Here is what I have so far:

`code`
 $(function() {
     $('form').submit(function() {
         $SendData(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));
         return false;
     });
 });
 
 $(function sendData(form_data) {
  $.ajax({
      url: '/my_data',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: form_data,
      dataType: 'json'
  });
 });

I am a total neophyte at JavaScript, so forgive this if it is wildly wrong. :-)

Comment: Sorry--I am not getting yet how to format code in responses

Comment: Please modify your first post with the updates. From there I can specify my answer better.

Comment: Hi Tom!

Yes--that post up there is really ugly! I apologize. I don't yet know how to format these bits to properly display.

However! I was able to get it all working and in fine fashion. Your answer, plus a little more research resolved into working code! Thanks again!